# how to specify end_time as current time in pandas data frame subset operation

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_final_data[(df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt.between_time('2019-01-10T12:13:13Z': NOW)]
```

Now is the current time of the system

```
TypeError: between_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end_time'
```

Also tried this

```
df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt.between_time('2019-01-10T12:13:13Z':)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues with your usage of [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

1. it is a function, so its arguments shall be separated by commas instead of colons
2. it selects, as the name implies, values between two *times*, not *datetimes*
3. it works only on the index, not on columns.

What you need is the following:

```
df_final_data[(df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt >= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-10T12:13:13Z')) & (df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt <= pd.to_datetime(NOW))]
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-4c608762ee3b> in <module>
      2                                ---> 4  (df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt >= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-10T12:13:13Z')) & (df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt <= pd.to_datetime(NOW))
      5                                   ]

/opt/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)

Comment: 1764 
   1765             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1766                 res = na_op(values, other)
   1767             if is_scalar(res):
   1768                 raise TypeError('Could not compare {typ} type with Series'

/opt/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1623 
   1624         if is_object_dtype(x.dtype):
-> 1625             result = _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
   1626 
   1627         elif is_datetimelike_v_numeric(x, y):

Comment: /opt/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
   1601         result = libops.vec_compare(x, y, op)
   1602     else:
-> 1603         result = libops.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
   1604     return result
   1605 

pandas/_libs/ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__richcmp__()

TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

Comment: this means that your `df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt` is of `str` type, not `datatime`. If your strings are of the same format as your sample start time, you could simply use `df_final_data[(df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt >= '2019-01-10T12:13:13Z') & (df_final_data.AlertTime_UTC_dt <= NOW)]`. Otherwise you'll have to convert the column to `datetime` first.

Comment: NameError: name 'NOW' is not defined

Comment: you said yourself in your question that NOW is the current time of the system, so I assume you have defined a variable NOW ????

Comment: if not create it: `NOW = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` (after you've done `import datetime`)

Comment: Thanks you , I used the following,

Comment: from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")